# Capybara testing with jQuery, Bootstrap, and jQuery-ui from CDN

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, rspec, capybara

I am getting jQuery, jQuery-ui, and Bootstrap from CDNs in my app. Since I switched over to using CDNs instead of gems, I am getting errors in my specs that they can't find `$`. Is there a way to download a copy of these scripts and have my specs use them instead of the ones from the CDN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply check which environment Rails is running:

```
if Rails.env.production?
  javascript_include_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"
else
  javascript_include_tag "/scripts/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js"
end
```

There is most likly a plethora of gems for this though.

### Added:

A nice eat the cake and keep it approach if you still want to use gems (like jquery-rails) and the sprockets pipe in development:

```
if Rails.env.production?
  javascript_include_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"
else
  javascript_include_tag "libs"
end
```

---

```
// assets/javascripts/libs.js
//= require jquery
```

This way you don't litter your repository with a bunch of vendor files.

Comment: I added an approach which allows you to use the sprockets pipeline for development/tests